# Event of tab switching with NVD3 graph will disturb rendering of graph in other tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, user-interface

I am using **NVD3** chart, on my dashboard, and it has three tab where, I have a code for graphs.  If I am switching tab, that time graph get collapsed on left side and throwing error like

```
d3.min.js:1 Error: <rect> attribute width: A negative value is not valid. ("-40").
```

Can anyone help me to get out from this issue?

My page is responsive so that I am not going to provide width manually.

Comment: Sorry, your question is clear but there is not code to work with or find possible solutions.

Comment: It get resolved, I used another approach for tab.